# Implementing Navigate Back and Navigate Forward button functionality for a WinForm TreeView control

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm

I have a WinForm app that has a TreeView control in it that usually has many nodes and I would like to implement functionality like Visual Studio's Navigate Back and Navigate forward functionality.

My gut reaction was to use a stack data structure as described here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2771e9b7-115d-4d10-8b31-12a2497a7724/how-go-back-button-in-the-windows-works-), which I copied here:

*Use the Stack class to store each visited node. When user clicks on a node call the Push method massing the url. When you need to go back call Pop method on Stack class wich will give you the last visited node and if you call it again it will give you the node before and it continues in that way. Ps: Stack class is a collection type of LIFO (Last in first out)*

But I start getting confused about how the Navigate Forward functionality works in VS or if perhaps should ideally work if I could rethink it. That's when my head started to hurt.

What if the user visited the following nodes

```
1,2,3,4
```

then hit Back twice to get to node 2

Then clicked on node 5.

Should the forward button even be enabled/available at this point? Please describe the algorithm and the data structures used. If you are using a stack, once you "go back" you lose where you came from.

So how does one implement the counterpart Navigate Forward functionality? All the Googling I've been doing is turning up Browser related tips for coding web apps and I am looking for a little direction to avoid mis-inventing a common algorithm that already been done.

Your thoughts would be welcomed.

Comment: I think the algorithm just depends on you. For example, if you want to store every selected node (without using Forward/Backward), just append every newly selected node to the end, such as for your example: `1,2,3,4` -> Back to `2` -> Select `5` -> Stack `1,2,3,4,5` -> Going back will select node `4` (not 2)... Another algorithm is inserting the newly selected after the current selected node in the stack: `1,2,3,4` -> Back to `2` -> Select `5` -> Stack: `1,2,5,3,4` -> Going back will select node `2`, going forward will select `3`...

Comment: Referring to the latter suggestion, if the user selected 6 next, would that be inserted as shown as 1,2,5,6,3,4 since we are inserting the newly selected at the current selected node? And hitting the forward button at that point will take them to 3? It sounds like I should be using a Linked List.

Comment: I think you don't need linked list, just use normal `List<>` and an `index` to save the current selected. You can also use 2 `Stack`, one for going backward from the current and the other for going forward from the current.

Comment: Good recommendations, thanks.

Comment: Storing the index makes little sense. Nodes in a tree don't have an index, they're not stored sequentially like in an array. You probably want to store TreeNode objects in your Stack/List collection class

Comment: This lead me to test the VS algorithm, and sometime it doesn't make sense... sometime it doesn't goes back where I was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an example. Not sure if that's what you need. Of course you can start on node 1 as well. You can also insert the new values at particular positions in the array and move other values up the array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] myValues = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
            Stack back = new Stack();
            Stack forward = new Stack();
            int maxPos = myValues.Length - 1;
            int minPos = 0;
            int currPos = myValues.Length - 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Initial Navigation Values {0}", string.Join(",", myValues));
            Console.WriteLine("User <- or -> keys to navigate between the values");
            Console.WriteLine("You are on Node 4");
            var key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            while (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow || key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                if (currPos == minPos && key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You cannot navigate back anymore");
                    key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                    continue;
                }
                if (currPos == maxPos && key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You cannot navigate forward anymore");
                    key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                    continue;
                }
                if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                {
                    forward.Push(myValues[currPos]);
                    currPos -= 1;
                }
                if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    back.Push(forward.Pop());
                    currPos += 1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("You are on Node {0}", myValues[currPos]);
                key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            }
        }
```